# Correct Namespace config for Sent/Drafts/Trash with dovecot

Tags: dovecot, imap, maildir

Dovecot seems to configure namespaces by default (`conf.d/10-mail.conf` and `conf.d/15-mailboxes.conf`) this way:

```
# 10-mail.conf
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
namespace inbox {
   inbox = yes
}
# 15-mailboxes.conf
namespace inbox {
   prefix = INBOX.
   mailbox Drafts {
     special_use = \Drafts
  }
  ...
}
```

Now some clients seem to get them right as `INBOX.Sent` (Thunderbird), others create `INBOX.INBOX.Sent` (K9-Mail).

I suppose there may be some confusion with maildir vs. mbox how to handle subfolders and i am unsure if it should be `prefix =` (empty) to solve the problem or if the `INBOX.` prefix is actually correct there and it's maybe a client problem.

Comment: I don't have the prefix in my config, what happens if you remove it?

Comment: not enabled before and got localized folders, so different clients had different Sent/Trash/... folders. With it, the name is localized by the client but the folder is used.